# Not removing aged data per HISTORY_RETENTION_PERIOD policy

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

**Environment**: SQL Server 2017 Enterprise running on Windows Server 2016 Standard

**Test Case**

Create 2 identical temporal tables (differ only by name) where 1 table has `HISTORY_RETENTION_PERIOD` set to 1 day. The other table is set to `INFINITE`.

**CODE:**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TemporalPurgeTestNew
(   TemporalPurgeTestNewId          int             IDENTITY(1,1)
,   InsertedDate                    datetime2(0)           
,   ModifiedDate                    datetime2(0)        
,   UpdateNum                       int         
,   CONSTRAINT  pk_TemporalPurgeTestNew  
        PRIMARY KEY (TemporalPurgeTestNewId)
,   SysStartTime        datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL
,   SysEndTime          datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END   NOT NULL
 ,  PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime,SysEndTime)) 
 WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON 
    (   HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.TemporalPurgeTestNewHistory
    ,   DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON
    ,   HISTORY_RETENTION_PERIOD = 1 DAY
    ));

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TemporalPurgeTestExistTbl
(   TemporalPurgeTestNewId          int             IDENTITY(1,1)
,   InsertedDate                    datetime2(0)           
,   ModifiedDate                    datetime2(0)      
,   UpdateNum                       int           
,   CONSTRAINT  pk_TemporalPurgeTestExistTbl
        PRIMARY KEY (TemporalPurgeTestNewId)
,   SysStartTime        datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL
,   SysEndTime          datetime2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END   NOT NULL
 ,  PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime,SysEndTime)) 
 WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON 
    (   HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.TemporalPurgeTestExistTblHistory
    ));

GO
```

Inserted 1 record in each table

Create a SQL Server Agent Job to modify the record in each table and let job run for 3 days.

On the 3rd day, verify table with retention period of 1 day has first day of data purged in associated history table and the 2nd history table still contain data from day one.

Alter 2nd table to set retention period to 1 day

**CODE:**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TemporalPurgeTestExistTbl
SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON 
    (   HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.TemporalPurgeTestExistTblHistory
    ,   DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON
    ,   HISTORY_RETENTION_PERIOD = 1 DAY
    ));
```

**EXPECTED**: data will be purged from 2nd historical table in same manner as 1st temporal table.

**ACTUAL**: aged data in 2nd historical table is not removed per retention policy set.

Is this expected behavior or am I missing a step in purging data in the second temporal table.

Comment: Please share the DDL of your table. Microsoft document says: "It is important to notice that only history tables with a clustered index (B-tree or columnstore) can have finite retention policy configured." maybe that's the case

Comment: DDL statements included.

Comment: Clustered index is created on the history table as it's created by default. In any case, if index does not exists, altering table to finite retention period will cause error.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I had the wrong assumption regarding Historical table purge.
I was expected the oldest data to be removed from table, but SQL Server does not guarantee order of data be be removed.
When I check by count of record, I can see data being removed.